# Screensaver startup script (batch or reg) GPO, silent install

Tags: group-policy, scripting, startup, windows

I have an application, which after it disconnects from a VPN connection, resets the screensaver settings. What I'd like to do is create a GPO script or batch file to run every time the user logs into the workstation, without the user having to confirm the modifications.

Currently I have this reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_UESR\Control Panel\Desktop]
"ScreenSaveActive"="1"
"ScreenSaverIsSecure"="1"
"ScreenSaveTimeOut"="450"
"SCRNSAVE.EXE"="ribbons.scr"
```

I've set this to run under GPO > UC > WS > Scripts > Logon > ScriptPath [Path to .reg file] | Script Params [regedit /s].

regedit /s as silent install.

Any suggestions one what might work better or fault in my setup?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at Group Policy Preferences - you can set "add this to the registry" directly in a group policy, without the need for a reg file and a script running regedit.

Although if you are running XP workstations they need to be on Service Pack 2, possibly with an XML update, to use GPO Preferences.

Comment: If you're running XP workstations, you might be better off to avoid GPPs, actually.  They're flaky on the Server 2003/XP OSes.